# Test - FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, automated-tests, robolectric

I'm trying to run a test with Robolectric and it has an integration with Firebase. I have a project MyProject - Test that I'll be using to run the tests in a real instance of the database.

The problem is that, when running cleanup before test, I have the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.cgbros.silkhub.activity.listener.LoginActivityUnitTest.cleanUp(LoginActivityUnitTest.kt:26) <28 internal calls>
```

The test file:
https://gist.github.com/augustoerico/e88d3e5b59ae5d023d83c114b8ffa708
(I tried to copy-paste the source here. Failed miserably...)

Any insights on how I can make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: When I last had this (earlier this morning) I'd forgotten to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the end of my app's `build.gradle`. Also have a look at some of the previous questions about this error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Default+FirebaseApp+is+not+initialized+in+this+process+null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. It's actually a conceptual problem. The problem is that I'm trying to use the Firebase Android SDK to run a test outside of the Android context. I mean, my test is not an Android application, and I'm trying to use the Android SDK. All `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` need a `Context` as a parameter.

So, what I have to do is to find a way to interact with my FirebaseDatabase. I think I can go with `firebase-admin`, or maybe use this one: https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j

Thank you for taking the time to help me (:

** Update **

I've opted to go with the Firebase REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

For future reference, I'm giving public full access, by tweaking the rules, so it is easier to write the tests setup and cleanup.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem and fixed it by initializing Firebase in the before step of my unit test:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
```

Comment: It worked! I initialized Firebase in my tests as you mentioned. I was trying to get the instance at onCreate FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(loggedException);

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue a few day ago and i solve it in the same way the error says. You get that error because you're trying to get an instance of `Firebase` without initialize it. Please add this line of code before you try to get an instance of Firebase like this:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Also, as Franks says, please be sure you have the following line of code added in your `build.gradle` file, `as the last line` of your entire file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to initialize Firebase in my test class, so I can populate it and clean it up. So, I can't just use "this" because it is not an instance of Context.

Comment: That's why s happening this. You cannot instantiete Firebase without an instance of Context. In this case create a method in your TestClass with the argument of Context. Then just call that method from the ActivityClass using as an argument an instance of Context. Will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me (: I think I was just trying to use the Firebase SDK in the wrong way, I think I should be using the REST API to populate the database and clean it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I used the most simple and straightforward approach.
Since you init your Firebase App in your Application, just create a variable there. For example,

```
//Your Application.class
open var isTestMode = false

onCreate(){
if(!isTestMode){
//Init your Firebase app
}
}
```

And then in Robolectric Application just extend your application and override the variable. In this case don't forget to provide configuration

```
@Config(application = TestApplication::class)
```

Answer (score 1):

The @Before approach did not fix the problem for me, because Firebase was called during app initialization. I was able to fix with this instead:

```kotlin
MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            if (Build.FINGERPRINT == "robolectric") {
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
            }
            logger.w("Using Firestore emulator")
            val firestore = Firebase.firestore
            firestore.useEmulator("192.168.1.102", 8080)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the above issue. Do all plugin download and checks by nuget. But in the end, I found the crashing was due to , Application Package Name not matching the one Assigned in Google Dev.
**Application package name must matche the one that assigned in the Google Dev. Console**

Answer (score -1):

after add this line and  then you get error

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

then you have to do that also

### add this line to Gradle (App)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

### add this line to Gradle (Project)

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

also check if no dependncy is missing and make sure you add google-services.json